# Rights vs permissions vs privileges

Tags: access-control, terminology, rbac

I have to write a node module for handling role-based access control. Users are stored in database, there are user groups, and there are system assets or functionality that users and groups can be given or denied access to.

I am considering the most appropriate terminology for these concepts:

- system asset/functionality = "right"?
- that a user is allowed to access certain asset/functionality = "permission"?

Comment: We cannot help you with this because there is no objective criteria here; its up to you. I have seen all three terms used in access control code. I use *permission* because *right* is something that you are entitled to instead of being granted and *privilege* is luxury; Think of it from the point-of-view of a moderator or adminstrator: they *have* to take adminstrative action. They are granted the permissions so that they can do their job - thats the only reason. And to me that is neither a right nor a privilege.

Comment: Are you aware that RBAC has defined terms? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control

Comment: You should not implement authorization yourself. There are many modules that implement rbac and ABAC out of the box. It'll save you time and you won't make implementation mistakes. Look into what NIST has to say on RBAC and ABAC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Role Based Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) is a well defined model, that comes with its own terminology. At minimum, RBAC has the following entities:

A `User` has one or more `Roles`.
A `Role` is a collection of `Permissions`.

A `Permission` (or *privilege*) is the *right* to perform an `Operation` (or *action*) on a `Resource` (or *object*).

So, from what you describe in your question, I would say that

1. your model is not complete yet (`operation` is missing);
2. your 'system asset/functionality' is a `resource`;
3. "that a user is allowed to access certain asset/functionality" is indeed a `Permission`

Answer (score -1):

#### Access rights

Determine the level of authority when working in the system.

Examples:

- Format disk in Windows NT and above may only group of administrators. Users can’t format disks.
- Right for changing display settings
- Right to login to system

Rights can be changed in policies.

#### Permissions

Permissions are sets to grant or deny access to resource (e.g. file, directory, printer) or operations (actions).

- For file: read, write, execute, change, delete.

Rights take precedence over permissions. For example, if a certain user does not have permission to “become the owner” of a particular file object, but at the same time we give him the right to become the owner of any object, then he, having given a request for ownership of the mentioned object, will receive it in his ownership.

But it's for OS, not for database. I think in database - role/permission

Comment: Do you have a reference or a source for these definitions? "Rights can be changed in policies" -- what policies? "Permissions are sets" -- sets of what? You state that Rights determine level of authority, but how is "right to log in" an authority? And how is that different from "granting access to resources"? And your definitions do not appear to be much different from each other. I'm afraid that these are definitions that you have tried to come up with yourself and they don't reflect official definitions.

Comment: In all RBAC documentation, "Rights" and "Permissions" are used synonymously, with "rights" being used as a general description of what Permissions modify. Please see the accepted answer for an example of a properly cited answer and the RBAC relationship between "permissions" and "rights".

Answer (score -2):

Permissions refer to the access granted for an object and determine what you can do with it.

Eg: Permissions on Linux file system `-rwx`

Rights refer to the ability to take action on an object - outside the scope of permissions.

Eg: Microsoft group policies add certain rights to group users

Privileges refer to the union of permissions and rights.

Source: ISC² Certified Information Systems Security Professional 8th and 9th editions Chapter 14

Comment: This, like the other answer, contains strange definitions. For example, how are rights different from permissions, even in GPOs? Can you provide an *actual* source backing up your definitions?

Comment: The source is written in my answer and is actually from CISSP edition 8th and edition 9th Chapter 14 first two pages. I added a few more explanation and examples to make it clearer.
Permissions refer to the access granted for an object and determine what you can do with it. Rights refer to the ability to take action on an object. Privileges is the combination of the other too.
It seems clear to me and it is the most appropriate generic answer for these definitions.

Comment: "CISSP" not a source, that's a certification. Did you mean the All-In-One Guide? Official ISC2 CISSP Guide? ISC2 CISSP Certified Information Systems Security Professional Official Study Guide? The book you seem to want to reference in your comment is a better source, except what you quote in your comment is ***not at all what you have written in your answer***... so your answer is not a quote at all. Which means you can't use that book as the source for your answer. So, I'm standing my by my first comment: your definitions are strange and not at all correct and your examples are mis-applied.

Comment: I did some quick googling, and the CISSP books I can find don't say what you have said at all. In fact, many say opposite things or other definitions entirely. So, please make sure that you are citing your sources, and quote them faithfully instead of trying to re-interpret them and claim that your interpretations are authoritative.

Comment: Debating about this does not seem constructive. Both ISC² Certified Information Systems Security Professional books define these terms as mentioned and on top of that, another person has already a similar answer to this, yet he/she was demoted. If we are talking about terms I firmly believe that these would be sufficient terminologies and are actually clear, even if you do not accept or understand them. If we are talking about real world scenarios then it's a discussion on a whole other level (eg how file system perms and groups between Windows and Linux systems are implemented).

Comment: This isn't a debate. This is wrong on the facts. And you still have the wrong source. Do you mean the study guide? If you don't have that correct, then I can't look up for myself what the book says. And what ISC2 books I can find do ***not*** say "outside the scope of permissions" or "union of permissions and rights". So, to sidestep debate, provide accurate details and point to where you have found these facts so that your answer is supported, even if I don't agree with what the book says. But as it stands, this looks like your own words and not what the book says.

Answer (score -3):

**Rights:**
Rights are basically type of tasks which users can perform for particular purposes.You assign rights to groups or users.

**Example:** 
The role of content managers is to access content but not with databases, so users that are content managers should have content management rights but not database management rights.

**Permission:**
Permissions are settings which determine what a user can do on items or resources for which they have rights in an organization.

**Example:**

Read: users can view data.

Write: users can edit or create data.

Delete: users can delete data

**Privileges:**
The privileges are assigned to one or more groups to permit a user of those groups to manage system modules.

**Example:**
To create a module for reporting in a website, a user needs its development rights and write permissions so that he can develop the module.

Comment: Do you have references or anything to back up your use of these terms this way? Your descriptions are not normal and do not conform to established definitions.